# How to have a nest queries in Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm facing an issue with Parse.

I have three classes : **Users**, **Posts**, **Likes**

I'm using pointers for the **Likes** class *User* pointing to **Users** Class, and *Post* pointing to **Posts** class.

[image: Likes class]

I'm retrieving all the posts and then I would like to see if the current user likes a post or not, and for that I'm nesting a query. the problem I have is that the posts are not updated with the like boolean value. I'm using that code :

```
func loaddata(limit:Int, skip:Int) {
    MainFunctions.getphones{(phones) -> Void in
        var indxesPath:[NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath]()
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Feed")
        query.whereKey("username", containedIn: phones)
        query.limit = limit
        query.skip = skip
        query.includeKey("from")
        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                if objects.isEmpty {

                }
                else {

                    for object in objects {
                        let Date = object.createdAt
                        let post = Post(time: Date!)
                        let Type = object.objectForKey("type") as? String
                        post.Post = object
                        post.Post_message = object.objectForKey("Text") as? String
                        post.comments = object.objectForKey("commentaires") as? Int
                        post.likes = object.objectForKey("likes") as? Int

                        // See if the current user likes a post 

                        let query_like = PFQuery(className:"Likes")
                        query_like.whereKey("Post", equalTo: object)
                        query_like.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
                        query_like.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
                            (like: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil && like != nil {
                                post.DoILike = true
                            } else {
                                post.DoILike = false
                            }
                        }

                        self.posts.append(post)
                        indxesPath.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.posts.count - 1, inSection: 0))


                    }

                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indxesPath, withRowAnimation:  UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    self.tableView.finishInfiniteScroll()
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                }

            }

        } else {
            self.tableView.finishInfiniteScroll()
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

        }
    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

`query_like.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` is asynchrone so  when you are adding the post to the posts array `self.posts.append(post)` `post.DoILike` will get it's default value. So make sure when appending post to posts you have already get if the user liked the post or not.

Comment: Yeah I know that, But how I can do that ??

Comment: put all code (inserting rows in tableview etc ...) inside the callback block